# Composition of functions not working

Tags: functions, symbols, custom-notation, system-variables

I am trying to set a function within a function. What I do is to first create a function with two arguments. Then I would like to set a new function with the same two arguments, in which the previous function is inside the new one. However, when I do this, it seems that it does not read it properly.

I would appreciate it if sb could tell me what I am doing wrong.

See code below.

```
    Subscript[p, 1][Subscript[q, 1] _, Subscript[q, 2] _] := 
 Subscript[α, 1] + γ Subscript[q, 2] + 
  Subscript[q, 1] Subscript[β, 1]
Subscript[Π, 1][Subscript[q, 1] _, 
  Subscript[q, 
   2] _] := (Subscript[p, 1][Subscript[q, 1], Subscript[q, 2]] - 
    Subscript[w, 1])*Subscript[q, 1]
Subscript[Π, 1][Subscript[q, 1] _, Subscript[q, 2] _]
```

And see the picture for help
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is meant to define a function Pi_A with arguments q_1 and q_2, which is also defined as a previously defined function with the same arguments.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dva98.png) attempt. Function arguments don't need to be subscripted. When calling a function, you provide arguments, not patterns with an underscore.

Comment: @Syed, Many thanks, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use [`Symbolize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/ref/Symbolize.html) of the built-in [`` Notation` ``  package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html) to use [`Subscript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html)s as symbols.

*Note: I symbolized both p and q below but you only need to symbolize q for the below to work.*

Only symbols can be used as parameter names for function definitions.  However, your subscripted expressions are not symbols.

```
Head @ Subscript[q, 1]
```

> ```
> Subscript
> ```

With the Notation package and its helpful palette you can `Symbolize` these expressions.

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[NotationTemplateTag[Subscript[p, _]]]
Symbolize[NotationTemplateTag[Subscript[q, _]]]
```

> [image]

Subscripted `p` and `q` are now parsed as symbols.

```
Head @ Subscript[q, 1]
```

> ```
> Symbol
> ```

One final step is we must use the [`Optional`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) syntax when using these `Symbolized` symbols as parameter names.

```
Subscript[p, 1][Subscript[q, 1] : _, Subscript[q, 2] : _] := 
 Subscript[α, 1] + γ Subscript[q, 2] + Subscript[q, 1] Subscript[β, 1]
```

Notebook view below; easier to read.

> [image]

You also have the ability to assign values to your symbolized subscripted symbols.

```
Subscript[q, 1] = 5;
Subscript[\[CapitalPi], 1][Subscript[q, 1], Subscript[q, 2]]
```

> [image]

`Symbolize`d symbols can be removed with [`RemoveSymbolize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/ref/RemoveSymbolize.html); also in the palette.

```
RemoveSymbolize[NotationTemplateTag[Subscript[p, _]] ]
RemoveSymbolize[NotationTemplateTag[Subscript[q, _]] ]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.